# Make bs4 navbar in content box

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel, laravel-blade

So i have problem with bs4 navbar so lets explain more about the problem:

I have page with content box that have container and i want above of it to put the navbar i want to make somethink like this [image]

But when i try to make it happend that:

[image]

So here is my html file

```
<title> {{ $title }} </title>


<!-- CSS -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}">
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.scrollbar/0.2.11/jquery.scrollbar.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.scrollbar/0.2.11/jquery.scrollbar.min.css"/>
```

```
<body class="scrollbar-inner">

<div id="particles-js"></div>
@if(!Auth::user())
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).on('load', function () {
            $('#userLogin').modal('show');
        });
    </script>
    @include('modals.login')
@endif


<div class="servername">
    {{ $heading }}
</div>
<h1 class="ip" onclick="CopyToClipboard('to-copy')">
    <div id="to-copy">{{ $main_ip }} <b class="fa fa-copy"></b></div>
</h1>


<div class="content-box">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
        <!-- Brand -->
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>

        <!-- Links -->
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
            </li>

            <!-- Dropdown -->
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    Dropdown link
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
<div class="maincontent-box">
</div>

    <div class="sidebar">
        @if(Auth::user())
            <div class="dropdown userPane">
                <button style="color:#000000; width: 111%; background: #D3D3D3" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"
                        data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <img src="http://cravatar.eu/head/{{ Auth::user()->username}}/128.png" width="32px;"
                         height="32px;"/> {{ Auth::user()->username }}
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" style="width: 111%">
                    <a class="dropdown-item">
                        <center>
                            <img src="http://cravatar.eu/head/{{ Auth::user()->username }}/128.png" width="32px;"
                                 height="32px;"/>
                        </center>
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-item">
                        <center>
                            Репутация: <span
                                class="badge badge-{{ Auth::user()->reputation == 10 ? 'success' : 'danger' }}">{{ Auth::user()->reputation }}
                                /10</span>
                        </center>
                    </div>
                    <div class="dropdown-item">
                        <center>В сървъра ли си?: <b>{{ Auth::user()->isLogged == 1 ? 'Да' : 'Не' }}</b></center>
                    </div>
                    <hr/>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ url('/account/password') }}">
                        Смени парола
                    </a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                        Нотификаций: <span class="badge badge-danger">5</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                        ични съобщения: <span class="badge badge-danger">5</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ url('/logout') }}">
                        <center>Излез</center>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endif
        <div class="side">

            <h5 class="boxes-title">Навигация <b class="fa fa-compass"></b></h5>

            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <a href="{{ url('/') }}" class="{{ request()->is('/') ? 'active' : '' }}"><b
                            class="fa fa-home"></b>
                        Начало</a>
                    <br>
                    <a href="{{ url('/shop') }}" class="{{ request()->is('shop') ? 'active' : '' }}"><b
                            class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></b> Магазин</a>
                    <br>
                    <a href="{{ url('/bans') }}" class="{{ request()->is('bans') ? 'active' : '' }}"><b
                            class="fa fa-gavel"></b> Банлист</a>
                    <br>
                    <a href="{{ url('/support') }}" class="{{ request()->is('support') ? 'active' : '' }}"><b
                            class="fa fa-question"></b> Поддръжка</a>
                    <br>
                    <a href="{{ url('/apply') }}" class="{{ request()->is('apply') ? 'active' : '' }}"><b
                            class="fa fa-file-o"></b> Кандидатури</a>
                    <br>
                    <a href="{{ url('/top-voters') }}" class="{{ request()->is('top-voters') ? 'active' : '' }}"><b
                            class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></b> Топ гласуващи</a>
                    <br>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="side">
            <iframe style="width: 300px;"
                    src="https://discordapp.com/widget?id=511173991168344069&theme=dark" width="350" height="500"
                    allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="{{ asset('js/particles.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/ptcls.js') }}"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/application.js') }}"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

My css file:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    background: url("https://i.imgur.com/CTT4cRp.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

a {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.77);
}

a:hover {
    color: #ffbd13;
}

.servername {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 100px;
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 40px;
    justify-content: center;
}

.ip {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    justify-content: center;
}

#to-copy:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

#particles-js {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
    left: 0px;
    background-image: url('');
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.content-box {
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 2px solid;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
    max-width: 80rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: white;
    margin-bottom: 20rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}

.active {
    color: #ffbd13;
}

.news-box {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    width: 90%;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 30px;
}

.maincontent-box {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    width: 90%;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-top: 6.6rem;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}


.boxes-title {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.sidebar {
    width: 90%; /*Changed*/
    bottom: 520px;
    margin: 30px;
}

.side {
    padding: 15px;
    bottom: 520px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .sidebar {
        width: 30%;
    }

    .news-box {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .maincontent-box {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .content-box {
        flex-direction: row;
    }
}

.userPane {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    top: 0;
    color: white;
    right: 0;
    width: 80%;
    justify-content: center;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .userPane {
        width: 90%;
    }
}
```

Please help me guys.. im trying to make it maybe 30 minutes without succedd! Thanks in advice!

Comment: Patience is a virtue, Try some more..

Answer (score 0):

hmm, maybe try with something like this :

```
<div class="content-box">

           <div class="navbar_position" >
   <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
        <!-- Brand -->
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>

        <!-- Links -->
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
            </li>

            <!-- Dropdown -->
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    Dropdown link
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
<div class="maincontent-box">
</div>
```

style:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .sidebar {
        width: 30%;
    }
      .navbar_position{
     position: absolute;
     width: 90%;
    }

    .news-box {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .maincontent-box {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .content-box {
        flex-direction: row;
    }
}
```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/uJKmTlYZtSgRDSqGk27W?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you do like this

```
<html> 
    <head>  
      <!-- bootstrap css here -->
      <!-- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/ --> 
    </head>

   <body> 


    <div class="container">   

     <nav> 
        <!-- This is inside container because the header is on the left side container only. -->
        <!-- nav src here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navs/ -->
     </nav>


       <!-- main content here -->
    </div>

    <div class="sidebar">   
       <!-- main content -->
    </div>

      <!-- bootstrap js here -->
      <!-- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/ -->
  </body> 

</html>
```

I hope that this will give you an idea.